# Delete from multiple tables with common column in one query?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete, micro-optimization

Micro optimization I know, this is more because I am curious.

I have two link tables,

```
blog_categories_posts => post_id, category_id  
blog_tags_posts       => post_id, tag_id
```

I am removing all links from both tables based on the `post_id`:

```
DELETE FROM blog_categories_posts WHERE post_id = {$id};
DELETE FROM blog_tags_posts WHERE post_id = {$id};
```

Anyway, I am wondering if it is possible to delete from both tables at once, and whether it would be a performance (whilst micro) hit or gain?

I imagine if it was to work:

```
DELETE FROM blog_categories_posts, blog_tags_posts where post_id = {$id}
```

or a similar syntax?

Comment: There was another question like this I found, maybe it will help? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is on the mysql website: [Delete Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

```
DELETE FROM tbl1, tbl2
USING tbl1
JOIN tb2 USING (id)
WHERE id = :id
```

So for your example it would be:

```
DELETE FROM blog_categories_posts, blog_tags_posts
USING blog_categories_posts
JOIN blog_tags_posts USING (post_id)
WHERE post_id = $id
```

It's also very easy to add many tables:

```
DELETE FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4, tbl5
USING tbl1
JOIN tb2 USING (id)
JOIN tb3 USING (id)
JOIN tb4 USING (id)
JOIN tb5 USING (id)
WHERE id = :id
```