# How I can remove rows from two tables with join in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

`Table1.`

```
id | name
 1 | Test
```

`Table2.`

```
id | post | table1_id
 1 | mypst| 1
```

I need to remove a row from `Table1` where `id=1` and all rows from `Table2` where table1_id=(1 is id from `Table1`).

I'm trying this:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.table1_id = Table1.id AND Table1.id = 1
```

but I'm getting error:

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.*

What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Comment: @sgeddes - Not a dupe. Different RDBMS. MySQL does support a multiple table delete syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing deletes from multiple tables in one query

```
DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE table1_id = 1;
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE id = 1
```

should be fine. Is there any specific reason you wish to do it using JOIN?

Comment: no, just interesting for my skills, thank you pretty much! I think this is even better solution.

Comment: @Marius - Not only shouldn't but can't. SQL Server doesn't have any syntax to delete from more than one table (though you can set up foreign keys with cascading deletes)

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you are doing things right and made a foreign key (Table2.table1_id = Table1.id). Then all you need is to set `ON DELETE CASCADE` on Table1.

In this case everything you should do is:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE id = 1
```

...and relax. This is data consistency, dude :)