# SELECT (with LEFT JOIN) sql query, to DELETE sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

This query SELECT sql that I wrote, I'd need to actually delete all the data it provides in output, just that I can not turn it properly in a DELETE sql query without running into a syntax error.

Here the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ps_attribute_impact AS at
LEFT JOIN
    ps_product_attribute AS prod_at
ON    at.id_product = prod_at.id_product
LEFT JOIN
    ps_product_attribute_combination AS comb
ON    prod_at.id_product_attribute = comb.id_product_attribute
WHERE comb.id_attribute='1' AND at.price='0.00' AND at.id_attribute='1' AND prod_at.price='0.00'
```

I've tried this 3 queries:

```
DELETE *
FROM ps_attribute_impact AS at
LEFT JOIN
    ps_product_attribute AS prod_at
ON    at.id_product = prod_at.id_product
LEFT JOIN
    ps_product_attribute_combination AS comb
ON    prod_at.id_product_attribute = comb.id_product_attribute
WHERE comb.id_attribute='1' AND at.price='0.00' AND at.id_attribute='1' AND prod_at.price='0.00'
```

and

```
DELETE ps_attribute_impact.*
FROM ps_attribute_impact AS at
LEFT JOIN
    ps_product_attribute AS prod_at
ON    at.id_product = prod_at.id_product
LEFT JOIN
    ps_product_attribute_combination AS comb
ON    prod_at.id_product_attribute = comb.id_product_attribute
WHERE comb.id_attribute='1' AND at.price='0.00' AND at.id_attribute='1' AND prod_at.price='0.00'
```

and

```
DELETE
FROM ps_attribute_impact AS at
LEFT JOIN
    ps_product_attribute AS prod_at
ON    at.id_product = prod_at.id_product
LEFT JOIN
    ps_product_attribute_combination AS comb
ON    prod_at.id_product_attribute = comb.id_product_attribute
WHERE comb.id_attribute='1' AND at.price='0.00' AND at.id_attribute='1' AND prod_at.price='0.00'
```

But I have not had any success.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Comment: In particular, this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11442104/219155

Comment: The problem is that I want to delete the results from all the tables "called in question" by JOIN, not only from the table ps_attribute_impact, can I do this?

Comment: MySQL does allow you to specify more than one table after the DELETE keyword: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html However, when trying to delete more than one table at once, you can end up with a big mess if you have foreign key dependencies between your tables.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for [multi table delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html) is like this

```
DELETE ps_attribute_impact 
  FROM ps_attribute_impact AS at 
  LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute AS prod_at 
    ON at.id_product = prod_at.id_product 
  LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination AS comb 
    ON prod_at.id_product_attribute = comb.id_product_attribute 
 WHERE comb.id_attribute='1' 
   AND at.price='0.00' 
   AND at.id_attribute='1' 
   AND prod_at.price='0.00'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the *logic* of the query, but the syntax for a `join` in a `delete` is:

```
DELETE at 
    FROM ps_attribute_impact at LEFT JOIN
         ps_product_attribute prod_at
         ON at.id_product = prod_at.id_product LEFT JOIN
         ps_product_attribute_combination comb
         ON prod_at.id_product_attribute = comb.id_product_attribute
    WHERE comb.id_attribute='1'  AND at.price = '0.00' AND at.id_attribute = '1' AND
          prod_at.price = '0.00';
```

Because you have comparisons on all the tables in the `where` clause, the `left join`s are really doing `inner join`.  For clarity, you should change them to `inner join`.