# Delete from multiple tables in MySQL with one query

Tags: mysql

I'm running into a problem with deleting from multiple tables.

```
DELETE FROM categories, products
WHERE categories.category_id = products.category_id 
    AND categories.category_id = 4;
```

Can anyone spot the mistake that I've made?
I'm getting the errorcode: 1064

Comment: do you have a database selected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Comment: Can there be an explanation on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it appears that you need to explicitly declare the join,  Did you look at the linked question? save for the table name it appears to be exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the foreign key on product table as on delete cascade. Then, when you delete category product table references will also be deleted

```
DELETE FROM categories WHERE  
   categories.category_id = 4;
```