# Trying to delete duplicate posts, getting database error instead

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to use the following code to use sql to delete posts from my wordpress site that have the same value for the 'source_link' meta key. Anytime I run this code though, it will not delete duplicates and instead I get a database error on my site. Does anyone see anything wrong this code or know why I'm getting database errors?

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE p, pm1
FROM 
    $wpdb->posts as p, 
    $wpdb->postmeta as pm1, 
    $wpdb->postmeta as pm2 
WHERE 
    p.ID = pm1.post_id
    AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
    AND pm1.meta_key = 'source_link' 
    AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
    AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value");
```

Answer (score 0):

What database error are you getting?

I think your problem might be with how you're referring to multiple tables in the statement.
I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql) on Stack Overflow that says it needs to use a JOIN statement.

Comment: My site no longer loads and instead you get a big fat databse error. I will try doing something like that. Im not an sql expert though so would you know how to use a join statement here?

Comment: It might be difficult to use a JOIN here because while the P and PM1 tables are linked using the = sign, the pm1 and pm2 are linked using a > sign.   
Try this:  
`DELETE p, pm1  
FROM  
    $wpdb->posts as p  
JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as pm1 ON p.ID = pm1.post_id  
JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as pm2 ON pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id  
WHERE  
    AND pm1.meta_key = 'source_link'  
    AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key  
    AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value`