# Convert multiples MySQL DELETE in only one

Tags: mysqli, row, sql-delete

I have the following queries:

```
DELETE FROM server_N1 where vencimiento <= '2015/01/08';
DELETE FROM server_N2 where vencimiento <= '2015/01/08';
DELETE FROM server_N3 where vencimiento <= '2015/01/08';
...
DELETE FROM server_N11 where vencimiento <= '2015/01/08';
```

I want to convert theses queries in only one query. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
DELETE
N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, N7, N8, N9, N10, N11 FROM server_N1 N1, server_N2 N2, server_N3 N3, server_N4 N4, server_N5 N5, server_N6 N6, server_N7 N7, server_N8 N8, server_N9 N9, server_N10 N10, server_N11 N11
WHERE
(N1.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N2.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N3.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N4.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N5.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N6.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N7.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N8.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N9.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N10.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08') AND
(N11.vencimiento <= '2015/01/08');
```

How can I do it?

Edit: The problem is when I trying to join all queries in only one, I receive the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM server_N2 WHERE vencimiento <= '2015/01/08'; DELETE FROM server_N3 W' at line 1
```

Edit: Code:

```
$fechaactual = '2015/01/08';
$delete = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM server_N1 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N2 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N3 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N4 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N5 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N6 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N7 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N8 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N9 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N10 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'; DELETE FROM server_N11 WHERE vencimiento <= '{$fechaactual}'");
```

Comment: Just wrap the original `delete`s in a transaction, if you want them all to take effect at the same time.

Comment: Is it what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes, but when I do it, I receive the following message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM server_N2 WHERE vencimiento <= '2015/01/08'; DELETE FROM server_N3 W' at line 1

Comment: @Fulbito . . . Can you edit your question with the full code that is generating that error?

Comment: @Fulbito  . . . mysqli_query() only takes one query.  Split them into separate calls.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one or more of the tables have no rows to delete.  Because there are no rows meeting one of the conditions, the result set is empty -- hence nothing is deleted.

If you knew that one of the tables had rows meeting the condition, then you could start with that table and use `left join` with the conditions in the `on` clause.  However, if you don't know which table has such rows, then the query is harder.

In the end, it is simpler *and* you probably get better performance to wrap the `delete` statements in a transaction, so they all take effect at the same time.

Of course, this begs the question why you have 11 tables with the same structure.  That is usually a sign of poor database design.  The records in those tables should probably all be in a single table, with a column defining the "N" value.  Then you wouldn't even need to ask this question -- a simple delete would suffice.

Try this:

```
DELETE s FROM server_N1 s where vencimiento <= '2015/01/08';
```