# Delete row from 2 tables in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Can anybody point what is wrong with my code? I have 2 tables and I am trying to delete a row from 2 tables. I was able to delete a row from 1 table but delete a row from 2 tables did not work. Here is my code:

```
String id = theId.getText();
String id2 = theId2.getText();
textArea.setText("");
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dealer", "root", "admin")) {
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person, cars WHERE driverID = ?, carID = ?");
    if (stmt != null) {
        stmt.setString(1, id);
        stmt.setString(2, id2);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
```

The error I got

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE driverID
= '1', carID = '1'' at line 1
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String id = theId.getText();
String id2 = theId2.getText();
textArea.setText("");
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dealer", "root", "admin")) {
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE person, cars FROM person, cars WHERE driverID = ? AND carID = ?");
        if (stmt != null) 
        {
            stmt.setString(1, id);
            stmt.setString(2, id2);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but i don't know why i still get that error. Any idea?

Comment: You need to separate the WHERE clause filters using `AND` or `OR`

Comment: this `driverID` and `carID` columns, which table does they belong to?

Comment: driverID is from person table, carID from cars table

Comment: Does any of these columns occurs in both tables? Also, can you try this : `DELETE person, cars FROM person, cars WHERE person.driverID = ? AND cars.carID = ?`

Answer (score 2):

Your constraints should be more like...

```
WHERE driverID = '1' and  carID = '1'
```

I'd also highly recommend that you make use of a `PreparedStatement`

See [Using PreparedStatement's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)for more details

Comment: I might be because there was another answer, which didn't show up in my browser till just now

Comment: Well I can confirm that you both answered at few seconds intervals. I don't think this is a real reason to downvote specially without leaving any comment; but anyway.