# SQL delete rows by selection of foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, dependencies, foreign-keys

I'm a beginner to SQL and would like to write a script that deletes rows from 2 tables of a MySQL database.

I have events and attendees and like to delete all attendee and event data from events that are older than 90 days.
So I need to find an array of event_ids of old events and then delete all attendees refering to any event_id in that array.

What's the best way to solve that? Here is my idea:

```
DELETE * FROM attendees WHERE event_id = ANY (SELECT id FROM events WHERE enddate <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -90 DAY))

DELETE * FROM events WHERE enddate <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -90 DAY)
```

Comment: Is the tables are connected with the foreign key constraints ?

Comment: attendees have a foreign key event_id that refers to the events table primary keys.

Comment: Your idea will work, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql) is a better solution. Also you can add a ON DELETE CASCADE foreign key.

Comment: you should use foreign key constraints

Comment: I did not create the tables and don't want to interfere other operations, so I don't want to use [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) with ON DELETE CASCADE. But I see it would be a great way to do this in general.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Didn't think I'd be on the right track with my code at all. But in the I just had to add `ANY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete query should not use *

```
DELETE  FROM attendees WHERE event_id = IN  (SELECT id FROM events WHERE enddate <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -90 DAY))


DELETE  FROM events WHERE enddate <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -90 DAY)
```

(EDIT: Added `ANY` to deal with multiple lines in subquery)

Comment: `ERROR: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`
How can I deal with that array in the subquery?

Comment: do you have enddate  column in attendees?

Comment: `ANY` works fine for me. What's the difference using `IN`?

Comment: any and in is almost the same but they do have differences .. Read here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a foreign key relationship from `attendees` to `event` with `on delete cascade`.

Then, when you delete an event, the attendees will automatically be deleted.

You can read more about foreign key relationships [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: I have not created the databases. But if this relationship has been set on creation and the events will be deleted (only second line of my code), this will mean, that attendees are also deleted automatically?

Comment: Just checked and that's a very nice way to do that, [find more](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)
Unfortunatelly that will affect other operations on that database I do not want to influence.

Comment: @user2014895 . . . I find it hard to imagine that you would want an `attendees` table that has an `event_id` that is not valid.  Maintaining the consistency is called relational integrity, and maintaining relational integrity is an important function of databases.