# Error on MySQL multi-table DELETE

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone could tell me what is wrong with the following mysql query?

```
DELETE FROM table1 as A, table2 as B WHERE A.delivery_status = '3' AND
A.delivered_on < '2015-11-26' AND A.delivery_id = B.delivery_id
```

> Error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `as A, table2 as B WHERE A.delivery_status = '3' AND A.delivered_on '`at line

I also tried `< DATE('2015-11-26')`  because `delivered_on` is a `datetime` field, with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

Table aliases in a multiple-table DELETE should be declared only in the table_references part of the statement. Elsewhere, alias references are permitted but not alias declarations. You must type:

```
DELETE A,B FROM table1 as A, table2 as B WHERE A.delivery_status = '3' AND
A.delivered_on < '2015-11-26' AND A.delivery_id = B.delivery_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DELETE FROM table1  A, table2  B WHERE A.delivery_status = '3' AND
A.delivered_on < '2015-11-26' AND A.delivery_id = B.delivery_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

DELETE table1 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.delivery_id = table2.delivery_id WHEREtable1.delivery_status = '3' AND table2.delivered_on < DATE($today) AND table1.delivery_id = table2.delivery_id";