# MySQL delete from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables,
first table (table1):

```
| Field    | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| who_id   | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ts       | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

second table (table2):

```
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| owner_id | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ts       | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| was_read | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to delete data from `table1` and `table2` in one query by criteria
            `WHERE table1.ts < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 AND table1.user_id = table2.user_id AND table1.who_id = table2.owner_id`

Need a query similar to this but with `LIMIT`:

```
DELETE t1, t2 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE t1.ts < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 
AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.who_id = t2.owner_id;
```

Columns id does not intersect

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql help?

Comment: The big problem with the `LIMIT`.  I saw these answers they will not help me

Comment: The tables have 30 million records

Comment: do you have any notion how long it will take to do the deletion? It'll probably be a bit faster if you use joins rather than the syntax you've got above. If it's a production system and the delete will take too long, maybe you need to schedule some downtime.

Comment: The MySQL docs quite clearly state that you can't use LIMIT with multi-table deletes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: Can you show how it looks with join? All the same, I'm probably going to break on two requests for each table and for table2 with join

Comment: @ADyson looks like a join to me, albeit non explicit syntax join

Comment: rephrasing your query using `INNER JOIN` : `DELETE t1, t2 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.who_id = t2.owner_id
WHERE t1.ts < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 
`

Comment: @Drew would the DB engine treat it the same way though? Maybe I was mis-educated, but I was always taught that explicit joins were more effective than implicit joins via the where clause