# DELETE data in multiple tables mySQLi Prepared Statement efficiently

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm deleting data from the dB in multiple tables.  I'm sending the data username over to `delete-member.php` using a modal to confirm (delete) like this:

```
<script>
    $('.delete-button').on('click', function (e) {
    var username = $(this).attr('data-id');
     $('.confirm-delete').attr('data-id',username);

    });
    $(".confirm-delete").on('click', function (e) {
        var username = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log(username);

        //Ajax for deleting category
        $.ajax({
            url: 'handlers/delete_member.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {username: username},
            error: function() {
                alert('Something went wrong');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Member Deleted");
            }
        });
        location.href="site_members.php?username="+username;
    });
</script>
```

Everything works fine here, I `$_GET` the username and delete the data.  The challenge I'm having is if that particular user has been using the system for awhile.  In order to do a hard delete of that user, I need to mk. sure that `username` is deleted in multiple tables.  15 to be exact.

Using prepared statements, I set about deleting each occurrence as follows:

```
if(isset($_GET["username"])) {
$userFromURL = $_GET["username"];

//delete member information from users
global $con;
$delete_mbrQ = mysqli_prepare($con, "DELETE FROM users WHERE username=?");
$delete_mbrQ->bind_param("s", $userFromURL);
$delete_mbrQ->execute();
$delete_mbrQ->close();

//delete member posts
$delete_postsQ = mysqli_prepare($con, "DELETE FROM posts WHERE added_by=?");
$delete_postsQ->bind_param("s", $userFromURL);
$delete_postsQ->execute();
$delete_postsQ->close();

//delete messages
$del_msgsQ = mysqli_prepare($con, "DELETE FROM messages WHERE user_to=? OR user_from=?");
$del_msgsQ->bind_param("ss", $userFromURL, $userFromURL);
$del_msgsQ->execute();
$del_msgsQ->close();
```

etc...(I won't put all 15 but you get the gist) I did this for all 15 tables where `username` occurs and it works fine.  However, looking at this big page of recurring code, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?  Can I combine this into one or two statements to achieve the same thing?

I've been researching on this, but most of what I've read talks more about setting up a foreign key, which I've done in some cases but clearly not for this.  I also don't find much for Prepared Statements and instances where the column names are different.  Any help, examples, links etc. would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

## You can use MySQL joins; `inner join` (or `left join`)

Using the examples you have above, you can construct a single SQL query that combines various tables together using join queries and delete all results from these joins.

```
DELETE users, posts, messages FROM users 
       INNER JOIN posts 
             ON posts.added_by = users.username
       INNER JOIN messages 
             ON messages.user_to = users.username OR messages.user_from = users.username
WHERE users.username= ?
```

This should do what you need, however with 15 tables this could easily be more vebose and possibly slower if your indexing is not well set out.

*Sources:*

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/
- [How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

---

## Also...

*To maintain MySQL efficiency you can simply wrap your PHP Prepared Statements in a loop and run the loop* per table *, depending on how your tables are set out this seems to be possibly easy but only* most *of the time. Some repetition may still remain.*

... Use foreign keys in a new table a `delete_table` which references the occurance of the row in all (15) other tables, then simply delete from the `delete_table` and watch the delete cascade!

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm trying to understand the solution you suggest: wrapping my Prepared Statements in a loop and running it per table.  Do you mean `while(something) {all of my prepared statements}` ?

Comment: @Raylene yes, kind of, but it would work fully if the column name `username` was the same across all tables and the count of `?` was the same, but this appears to only be so on *some* iterations so ..... it can be done but requires more *loop-exception* coding

Comment: gotcha.  ok thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can define a foreign key on a column that cascades deletions once the referenced row gets deleted. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

You can alter your `posts` table so that the `added_by` column becomes a foreign key, which means that its values identify rows in the referenced table. Once a row in the `users` table gets removed, the database must take an action on all the rows in the `posts` table that reference the removed user row to maintain consistency. You can choose not to allow the removal if any `post` instances exist for the removed user or you can instruct to also remove all `post` instances when that happens. You can do it with this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD FOREIGN KEY (added_by) REFERENCES users (username) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: The OP has already mentioned foreign keys and how they want to find another variation without foreign keys to do the same thing