# Is there any other way to delete rows from multiple tables without creating foreign key between tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

This code does not work. Without creating foreign key between tables how can I delete data from multiple tables that matches the conditions? How can I write a 2 query and send it with PHP-PDO

```
$query = "DELETE FROM category, bookmark WHERE (bookmark.category = ? AND category.name = ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$categoryName, $categoryName]);
```

I am using "?" to prevent from sql injection.
This is the error I get.

> JavaSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
>   (bookmark.category = 'Java' AND category.name = 'Java')' at line 1

Comment: [How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3331992)

Answer (score 1):

In multi-table DELETE you **MUST** specify the tables which records must be deleted:

```sql
DELETE category, bookmark
FROM category, bookmark 
WHERE (bookmark.category = ? AND category.name = ?)
```

See [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  DELETE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html), section "Multiple-Table Syntax". The names of tables which records must be deleted are **NOT** enclosed into square brackets as optonal (2nd row of query text in both syntax variants).