# MySql Event to Delete Data from 2 Tables Older Than 2 Months

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

Im new to MySql events and I never used them before so please to bear with me.
With My DB I have **order_details** and **invoices** tables which I need to create an **Event** to delete all the records older than **2 months** and `where order_details status = 5` and `invoices status = 3`
and I want the event to make the deleting every **day at 3AM** How I may accomplish this
Any help will be much appreciated

**Update :**

Both tables have timestamp column named **created_at**

**Tables Definition**

A - **order_dateils** :

- id
- order_bar
- description
- status
- created_at

B - **invoices** :

- id
- invoice_id
- status
- created_at

Comment: Which of the 2 questions here (delete and create event) are you having problems with. AND where order_details status = 5 and invoices status = 3 is not clear nor is how you link orders to invoices (if that is the intention).

Comment: @P.Salmon Actually i saw to many examples for using events to delete from 1 table a time, in my case i have two tables both have timestamp column created_at and the order_details status must be =5 and the invoices status must be = 3 so my question is that possible

Comment: Please add table definitions for order_details and invoices

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: @P.Salmon No my friend, i know how to delete from tables what Im looking for is an Event to do the deleting every day  at 3AM

Comment: Creation and scheduling events is covered here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html and is pretty straightforward did you try something and is there any specific problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE EVENT delete_every_day
        ON SCHEDULE
          EVERY 1 DAY STARTS DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL'1 3' DAY_HOUR)
        -- Will delete every day record from invoices with status = 3 and more than 2 
        -- month old, and the order_details with status = 5 and more than 2 month old
        -- It will start deleting next day at 3:00 AM.
        DO
          BEGIN
            DELETE FROM your_schema.invoices
                 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,created_at, NOW()) > 2
                 AND status = 3;
            DELETE FROM your_schema.order_details
                 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,created_at, NOW()) > 2
                 AND status = 5;
          END
```

I hope this may answer your question. Make sure to include your schema (database name) with your table name such as [schema_name.table_name] to make sure the event is associated with the right tables. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but before trying it isn't the TIMESTAMPDIFF missing the months (the unit) ?

Comment: @Ali Adil, You're100% right. My wrong. There must be like "TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, created_at, NOW()). Sorry for that. I just edit it!

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1 3' DAY_HOUR) DO BEGIN DELETE FROM forval_DB.invoice WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH' at line 1

Comment: I cannot identify any SQL Syntax mistake in the code. I'll appreciate you to point it out if you do.

Comment: The error was in the DATE_ADD function, missing the INTERVAL clause. It's fixed now!