# Delete records From Multiple Table using where IN clause

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-delete

I want to delete data from 2 tables based on plan id which comes from the plan_temp table using WHERE IN .. I would be very grateful if you guys help me

**this is my code now I want to make this a single query**

```
DELETE FROM plan WHERE id_plan IN(SELECT id_plan FROM plan_temp WHERE no=1184);


DELETE FROM plan_temp WHERE id_plan IN(SELECT id_plan FROM plan_temp WHERE no=1184);
```

Comment: The question has already been answered here [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: thanks for the answer but it's different from what i asked

Answer (score 0):

Use an INNER JOIN to find the rows  in both tables

```
DELETE t1,t2 FROM plan t1
        INNER JOIN
    plan_temp t2 ON t2.id_plan = t1.id_plan 
WHERE
    t1.id_plan IN (SELECT id_plan FROM (SELECT * FROM plan_temp) t3 WHERE no=1184);
```

Please test all queries in a test environment with backup, to see if this is really what you want

Comment: doesn't work "Table 't2' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't delete two separated tables.

```sql
DELETE FROM plan WHERE id_plan = 1184

DELETE FROM plan_temp WHERE id_plan = 1184
```

But, you can use **Inner Join** to delete both values from two tables. So, it has to be like that;

```sql
DELETE  plan, plan_temp FROM plan INNER JOIN plan_temp
Where
plan.id_plan = plan_temp.id_plan and id_plan = 1184;
```