# How to do a "DELETE" relational database with another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to have a relational data between two table with `DELETE` query.
I don't know what keyword should I search and such confusing for me to learn relational database.

So in this case, I want to **delete one of the user data** in the `user` table.
So the `buy_product` table which contains the `user_id` column will also be deleted **along with the rows in it**.

This is `user` table:

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Doe |

This is `buy_product` table:

| id_product | name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cookies | 2 |
| 2 | Pizza | 2 |
| 3 | Burger | 1 |

For example, if I run the `DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = 2` query, the result is:

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |

And `buy_product` table with `user_id` = 2 also deleted the data that I want **without** run `DELETE FROM buy_product WHERE user_id = 2` query like this:

| id_product | name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Burger | 1 |

I think for all understandable answers means a lot to me. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you defined a foreign key constraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE` between `buy_product` and `user` then deleting a row from the parent table `user` will automatically delete the related rows in the child table `buy_product`.

For example, `buy_product` could be created as:

```
create table buy_product (
  id_product int,
  name varchar(50),
  user_id int references user (user_id) on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: Using `ON DELETE CASCADE` with foreign key is solving my problem with your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should configure cascading deletion such that when a record is deleted from the `user` table all dependent records are also deleted from the `buy_product` table.  In lieu of that, we can try doing a delete join here:

```sql
DELETE u, bp
FROM user u
INNER JOIN buy_product bp
    ON bp.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = 2;
```